# Defining the action of a group on a set in GAP

Tags: gr.group-theory, gap

Let $H$ be a subgroup of the automorphism group of a group $G$ and $S$ is a collection of subsets of the group $G$ with a given size. The group $G$ is defined via free group and relations in GAP. Moreover, the action of the group $H$ on the set $S$ is $s^h:=h^{-1}(s)$, where $s \in S$ and $h \in H$. To find the orbits of this action with GAP, the command Orbit(H, S, act) is applicable but defining the action "act" as a function in GAP, gave us an error. How can we define this action in GAP?

Comment: Have you tried `Orbit(H,S,OnSets)`?

Comment: Yes, this implies an error too.

Comment: For example, this works for me: `F:=FreeGroup(2); G:=F/[F.1^2,F.2^3,(F.1*F.2)^3]; A:=AutomorphismGroup(G); H:=Subgroup(A,[A.1,A.4]); Orbit(H,Set([G.1,G.2]),OnSets);`

Comment: Yes, this also works with Orbit(H,[G.1,G.2],OnSets); but for a subset K of the power set of the group G in which all elements have the same size which can be produced by a program in GAP, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that you need set families. How about `OnSetsSets` then? Say, with my example, `Orbit(H,Set([Set([G.1,G.1*G.2]),Set([G.1,G.2])]),OnSetsSets);` works

Comment: Your welcome. Thank you very much, in my case, Orbit(H,Set(K),OnSetsSets); works.

Comment: Glad that it works. That said, I believe your question does not actually belong here.

Comment: yes, maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap would be more suitable